# klaR NaiveBayes warnings "Numerical 0 probability for all classes..."

Tags: r, naive-bayes

I'm working on a "first classification" level project using [this dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/statlog+(german+credit+data)). My code below for reference.

```
library(klaR)

# Load data
cdata = read.csv("credit-g.csv")

# Split data into predictors and class variable
predictors = cdata[,-length(cdata)]
class = cdata$class

# Split into training set and test set
train_index = createDataPartition(cdata$class, p=.75, list=FALSE, times=1) 
training_predictors = predictors[train_index, ]
training_class = class[train_index]
test_predictors = predictors[-train_index, ]
test_class = class[-train_index]

# Train a Naive Bayes model based on the training data
model = NaiveBayes(training_predictors, training_class)

# Apply the model to make predictions for the test data
predictions = predict(model, test_predictors)

# Create a confusion matrix to evaluate the quality of the model
confusionMatrix(predictions$class, test_class)
```

The code works and I'm getting reasonable results, except that the `predict` function returns a note that "There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)". When I enter the `warnings()` command, I get the output below:

```
Warning messages:
1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  Numerical 0 probability for all classes with observation 1
2: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  Numerical 0 probability for all classes with observation 2
3: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  Numerical 0 probability for all classes with observation 3
4: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  ...
```

...and so on for the 1st 50 straight, and presumably all observations.

There shouldn't be any unique observations in this dataset to cause this, and it definitely doesn't make sense that all observations would be zero probability. To verify this, I've tried using the `threshold` parameter in the `predict` function, using the laplace correction model parameter `lF`, and removing low variance predictors from the dataset using `nearZeroVar()`; all to no effect.

Like I said, the confusion matrix still shows good results and I can submit the project as is, but it bugs me that I don't know why these warnings are happening. I really appreciate any feedback!

Comment: Not solving your question but may help:
> options(nwarnings = 1000) will increase the number of warnings displayed. The warning message is supposed to occur when when the observation is an extreme outlier.